# Delphi XE8 отображение даты из файла в заголовок формы

Tags: delphi, form, ini, delphi-xe8

у меня есть файл priud.f где я храню период даты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно отобразить период даты в заголовки формы

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  ini:TIniFile;
begin
  ini:=TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'priud.f');
  frmPriud.dtp1.DateTime:=ini.ReadDateTime('priud','d1',Now);
  frmPriud.dtp2.DateTime:=ini.ReadDateTime('priud','d2',Now);

  ShowScrollBar(DBGrid1.Handle,SB_HORZ,False);
  ShowScrollBar(Form2.Handle,SB_HORZ,False);

  Form1.Caption:='Реестр '+ini.WriteDateTime('priud','d1',frmPriud.dtp1.DateTime)+'/'+ini.WriteDateTime('priud','d2',frmPriud.dtp2.DateTime);

  fillterQuery;
end;
```

сделал таким образом но у меня выходить ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите пожалуйста с кодом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ini.WriteDateTime` ничего не возвращает - это процедура, а не функция. Поэтому ее нельзя использовать в строковом выражении.

```
Form1.Caption:='Реестр ' + ini.ReadString('priud', 'd1', '') + 
  '/' + ini.ReadString('priud', 'd2', '');
```

Comment: как сделать правильно ответьте пожалуйста

Comment: все получилось но в заголовке выходить дата и время как сделать чтобы отображалась только дата?

Comment: @ariana, обрезать строку с датой и временем используя функцию SubString http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Method.asp?NameSpace=system&Class=String&Type=Class&Method=SubString